# onActivityResult not triger in TabHost child activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost, onactivityresult

I have a problem with Tab Host and the activity in a tab when use startActivityForResult but the onActivityResult **does not triger.**

Class A is a main tabhost

A.java

```
    setContentView(R.layout.a);
    mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("tab1")
            .setContent(new Intent(this, B.class));
```

Class B is a activity as a child of tab host

B.java

```
public class B extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView image;
private int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_b);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(B.this);
            builder.setMessage("Select Picture?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_IMAGE);

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancle", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
}

}


protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == B.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want ImageView **image** in B.java change its image after select from a gallery. But when I do select, it won't change anything.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: First of all get rid of "activity as tabs" ... such approach was deprecated 4 years ago ...

Comment: Hi @Selvin, thank you for your suggestion. I'm now learning how to use fragment as tab. But in short period of time I have to go with activity first.